# Codeigniter: Why is my database function call no longer parsed in further controllers that I am creating?

Tags: codeigniter

Codeigniter: Why is my database function call no longer parsed in further controllers that I am creating even though I have done a similar query in previous controllers; and they are working just fine? Using output->profiler(), I found out that the database function call in the create_student() function is not parsed. What is strange to me is why the same function structure worked in previous controllers I had created.The following code tag works fine in other controllers using related method name like `public function create_group()`, `public function create_class()`. The same pattern is repeated.

```
 public function create_student(){
  $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
 if($this->input->is_ajax_request() && $this->input->post('ajax') == 1){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name[]', 'First Name', 'trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[20]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name[]', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[20]');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->output->set_status_header('400');
    echo '<span class="admin_validation_error" style="color:#ff0000">'.validation_errors().'</span>';

    } else {
$first_name = $this->input->post('first_name');
$last_name = $this->input->post('last_name');
if($this->student_model->create_student($first_name, $last_name) == true){
 echo '<span class="validation_success" style="color:green; font-weight:bolder">Well done! Student(s) successfully created.</span>';
}

        }

 }else{
    redirect('errors/not_found');
 }
}
```

Comment: elobarate more on this. what you did what works and what didn't work ?? clearly specify !!

Comment: Is the model being loaded in these other controllers?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what was wrong. It's funny though. I failed to include the username field in the subsequent tables I was creating. This had made it impossible for me to execute queries or load Datatable. The username field is present in the former tables I had created and needs to be in all the tables I am yet to create for the application. Thanks guys for giving me a clue. Cheers